# PHP assignment with a default value

Tags: php, variable-assignment, default-value

What's a nicer way to do the following, that doesn't call f() twice?

```
$x = f() ? f() : 'default';
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In PHP 5.3, you can also do:

```
  $a = f() ?: 'default';
```

See [the manual on ?: operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: +1 since I haven't seen that used in any of my books that cover PHP 5.3. Very good to know.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work fine:

```
$x = f() or $x = 'default';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function f()
{
  // conditions 
  return $if_something ? $if_something : 'default';
}

$x = f();
```

Comment: Ah, good answer. I meant for f() to be something we don't have control over and in fact the way this came up for me it wasn't a function at all but `$_REQUEST['foo']` so it wasn't an efficiency issue so much as a typing issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = ($result = foo()) ? $result : 'default';
```

[test](http://codepad.org/c9KgT8TF)

Comment: This works, but it looks like it can be done more cleanly, with no temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to a variable. Testcase:

```
function test() {
        echo 'here';
        return 1;
}

$t = test();
$x = $t ? $t : 0;
echo $x;
```